# MongoImport: Error inserting Documents

Tags: mongodb, csv, import, azure-storage, mongoimport

I've got a quite big csv file (300mb) with 75k records.
I'm trying to import it form my local disk (previously dowloaded form azure storage) to my database with mongoimport, but still getting this error:

```
error inserting documents: Message: {"Errors":["Request rate is large"]}
ActivityId: 47a93710-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Request URI: /apps/80fe604c-b810-41b3-9f20-8225fbc49263/services/6fbc8a68-c81c-4442-a4b9-51fe058e9434/partitions/f083c6db-2179-429f-979b-d3d78d52af9c/replicas/131521577121053793p
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution. For those who want to know :
I added --batchSize 'sizeOfBatch' to my mongoimport command